# How to handle 20~ Tasks/Threads With different cancellation tokens

Tags: c#, multithreading, telegram

I already asked the same question yesterday but i was not able to explain my problem properly, and the answer did't solve my problem.
I have telegram bot that post users messages in a infinity loop for them , each user
gets his own long running task and while he not pressing "stop" on the reply keyboard the task continue to run .
I have the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Telegram.Bot;
using Telegram.Bot.Args;
using Telegram.Bot.Types;
using Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums;
using Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups;


namespace MyBot
{

    public class Telegram
    {
        public static TelegramBotClient Bot;

        public static CancellationTokenSource Source { get; set; }


        public static async Task Main()
        {
#if USE_PROXY
            var Proxy = new WebProxy(Configuration.Proxy.Host, Configuration.Proxy.Port) { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
            Bot = new TelegramBotClient(Configuration.BotToken, webProxy: Proxy);
#else
            Bot = new TelegramBotClient(Configuration.BotToken);
#endif
            var me = await Bot.GetMeAsync();
            Console.Title = me.Username;

            Bot.OnMessage += BotOnMessageReceived;
            Bot.StartReceiving(Array.Empty<UpdateType>());
            Console.WriteLine($"Start listening for @{me.Username}");

            Console.ReadLine();
            Bot.StopReceiving();
        }


        //-----------------------------BotOnMessage----------------------------------------------------------------------
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private const string case1 = "Start posting";
        private const string case2 = "Stop posting";

        public static async void BotOnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
        {

            var replyKeyboardMarkup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();

            var message = e.Message;
            if (message == null || message.Type != MessageType.Text)
                return;

            switch (message.Text)
            {
                //----------------------------Start Post--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                case case1:
                    StartPosting(message);
                    await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId: message.Chat.Id, text: "Start post", replyMarkup: new ReplyKeyboardRemove());
                    break;
                case case2:
                    await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId: message.Chat.Id, text: "Stop post", replyMarkup: new ReplyKeyboardRemove());
                    Source.Cancel();
                    break;

                //----------------------------Keyboard-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                case "/start":
                    await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, "Choose an option:", replyMarkup:
                         replyKeyboardMarkup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup(
                    new KeyboardButton[][]
                    {
                        new KeyboardButton[]
                        {
                             new  KeyboardButton(case1),
                        },
                         new KeyboardButton[]
                        {
                             new  KeyboardButton(case2),
                        },

                    },
                    resizeKeyboard: true
                    ));
                    break;
            }
        }

        //------------------------------Post starts-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        public static void StartPosting(Message message)
        {
            Source = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var ct = Source.Token;

            Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    //some await
                    //some long code
                }

            }, ct, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();

        }



    }
}
```

When the user press on the start button which is case1: in the usecase , the code send him to StartPosting() function , from there he get a new cancellation token and gets into the long running task with his own cancellation token right ? .. then he easily press on the stop button , then he goes to case2: in the use case , and "Source.Cancel()" cancel the task... until now everything works fine.

But lets say user1 still in his task ok ? ... then user2 press on "Start" and going to StartPosting() function , he gets his own cancellation token again (Source = new CancellationTokenSource())
and then he gets into the task in parallel with user 1.

when one of the users decided to stop posting while the other still in his task, he going to case2: from there the Source.Cancel(); is activated and cancel all tasks !
I can't figure what iam doing wrong ...  i have the

```
public static CancellationTokenSource Source { get; set; }
```

which have get and set .. each user have get and set for his own cancellation token right ? so what wrong here , why its cancelling all task ?
if someone have any other solution to post message for sevral users in parallel without using tasks or threads and each user will have his own task.delay it will be fine .

sorry for my english iam trying my best to explain . if somone will find a solution i will very very very apriciate it!

Comment: “static” is quite possibly a problem. 1) a static variable is shared between all instances and 2) and all cancellations tokens created from the token source are linked to the source and will respond to it’s ‘Cancel’.

Comment: It would probably be useful to actually create new (possibly linked) token sources and use a method to associate them, and the resulting tokens, with individual tasks instead of using the shared-state static value. Creating new bot instances (with their own *non-static* fields for their specific cancellation tokens / sources) might help with this..